# What subset of a functions domain leads to a positive value for the function?

Tags: real-analysis

First time posting on here, glad it exists. So I'm trying to essentially understand what "percentage of a function's domain gives a positive value to the function."

My first intuition is the following:
Say you have a real function $F$ in $\Bbb R^1$ that is a function of $n$ real variables $\{x_i\}$. You can write the total "positive region of the function" as

$$\int d[x_i] F[x_i] \Theta[F]$$

where the measure $d[x_i]$ integrates over all variables $x_i$ and $\Theta$ is the Heaviside step function. Then if you want to know how much of this function is positive, you can just take the ratio of the quantity defined above to the total "amount of the function":

$$\int d[x_i] F[x_i].$$

The ratio should thus be:

$$r = \frac{\displaystyle\int d[x_i] F(x_i) \Theta[F]}{\displaystyle\int d[x_i] F[x_i]}.$$

The only problem is that this $r$ depends on the domain. Take $F[x] = 1-x^2$ for example, as pointed out by another user on another website. If you take your domain to be from $-1$ to $1$, then $r = 1$, but as you continue expanding your domain all the way out to $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, $r \to 0$. In general, for non-periodic functions, you would expect to see $r->0$ or $\to 1$. Periodic functions should converge to a finite number $\in [0,1]$.

Question then is, is there a volume-independent way of understanding what sets of $\{x_i\}$ admit positive values for $F[x_i]$?

**EDIT:** After thinking about this problem a bit more, I've realized that

$$
r = \frac{\displaystyle\int d[x_i] F(x_i) \Theta[F]}{\displaystyle\int d[x_i] F(x_i) \Theta[F] - \displaystyle\int d[x_i] F(x_i) \Theta[-F]}
= \frac{\displaystyle\int d[x_i] F(x_i) \Theta[F]}{\displaystyle\int d[x_i] \rm{abs}( F(x_i) )}
$$

is a better suited function since

$$\displaystyle\int d[x_i] F(x_i) \in [-\infty,\infty].$$

Comment: Also if anyone could direct me towards a text or paper that addresses this concept, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I don't see how you're going to get a domain-independent way of figuring out the proportion of domain where a function is positive --- of course the proportion is going to depend on the domain. If you try to get around that by taking limits at infinity, what do you do if those limits don't exist, e.g., for something like $\sin(\log x)$, which is positive for a long time, then negative for a much longer time, then positive for a much, much longer time, and so on?

Comment: HI Gerry thanks for the comment. I agree that it's not exactly clear, I was hoping for a suggestion, but perhaps there just isn't a domain independent way.